# Update ListItem

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

Solved it with a hiddenfield control:

```
    public void MyData(string prod)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("YourList");

        if (myList!=null)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = string.Format(
                "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ProductNumber' />" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith></Where>", prod);
            query.RowLimit = 10;

            SPListItemCollection items = myList.GetItems(query);

            foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
            {
                TextBox_NameList.Text = listItem["Title"] != null ? listItem["Title"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_ListPriceList.Text = listItem["ListPrice"] != null ? listItem["ListPrice"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_ProdNumList.Text = listItem["ProductNumber"] != null ? listItem["ProductNumber"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_ColorList.Text = listItem["Color"] != null ? listItem["Color"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text = listItem["MoreInformation"] != null ? listItem["MoreInformation"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                HiddenField_ID.Value = listItem["ID"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

My button code:

```
        protected void Button_UpdateProd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
         //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPList myList = web.Lists["Extern Products"];
        int listItemId = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField_ID.Value);

        //Considering you have the ID of the List Item
         SPListItem itemToUpdate = myList.GetItemById(listItemId);

        if(itemToUpdate != null)
        {
            itemToUpdate["Title"] = TextBox_NameList.Text;
            itemToUpdate["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNumList.Text;
            itemToUpdate["Color"] = TextBox_ColorList.Text;
            itemToUpdate["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPriceList.Text;
            itemToUpdate["MoreInformation"] = TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text;

            itemToUpdate.Update();

            TextBox_NameList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ListPriceList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ProdNumList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ColorList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text = string.Empty;
       }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you saving List Item Id somewhere in third web part ? You need to save the ID column somewhere on selection!

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Tick mark the answer below!!

Comment: I cant within two days it says... So i've putted my answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to save the ID, its automatically generated for you! "ID" is a read-only column, and it gets auto-increment each time you add a new item!

Where you have all the textboxes, take a HiddenField there, name it accordingly!

```
public void MyData(string prod)
{
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("YourList");

    if (myList!=null)
    {
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = string.Format(
            "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ProductNumber' />" +
            "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith></Where>", prod);
        query.RowLimit = 10;

        SPListItemCollection items = myList.GetItems(query);

        foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
        {
            TextBox_NameList.Text = listItem["Title"] != null ? listItem["Title"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            TextBox_ListPriceList.Text = listItem["ListPrice"] != null ? listItem["ListPrice"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            TextBox_ProdNumList.Text = listItem["ProductNumber"] != null ? listItem["ProductNumber"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            TextBox_ColorList.Text = listItem["Color"] != null ? listItem["Color"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text = listItem["MoreInformation"] != null ? listItem["MoreInformation"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            HiddenField_ID.Value = listItem["ID"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then on Update button click

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

 SPList myList = web.Lists["Extern Products"];
 int listItemId = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField.Value);

 //Considering you have the ID of the List Item
 SPListItem itemToUpdate = myList.GetItemById(listItemId);

    if(itemToUpdate != null)
    {

            listItem["Title"] = TextBox_NameList.Text;
            listItem["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNumList.Text;
            listItem["Color"] = TextBox_ColorList.Text;
            listItem["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPriceList.Text;
            listItem["MoreInformation"] = TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text;

            listItem.Update();

            TextBox_NameList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ListPriceList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ProdNumList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ColorList.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text = string.Empty;

   }
```

For **delete** simply use `listItem.Delete();` instead of `listItem.Update();`

You don't need SPQuery in this case, since it is one Item you want to update and you have the ID for it!

**Extra Information on SPQuery**

Here is list of all operations available in CAML Query 
[Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx)

For ease in CAML Queries, you can try one of the CAML Query Builders:
http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/
http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

I hope this helps

Comment: If works, please delete all the comments, add complete code in Question and your description in Question too! - for delete simply use `listItem.Delete();` instead of `listItem.Update();`

Comment: Also, mark the answer as correct.. and close all your previous questions by marking as answer! Also ask your partner Martin to close the questions too!